# Digispark uploading not working in KDE Neon (Linux)

Tags: linux, digispark

I am using KDE Neon and have downloaded the Arduino IDE via the Snap store. It worked well with the ESP8266 and other Arduions. But when I tried to upload a simple sketch or an example sketch to my Digispark, I get an error message. I have selected the right Board and the micronucleus programmer. I have also installed libusb. But I always get the following error message:

/home/myusername/snap/arduino/41/.arduino15/packages/digistump/tools/micronucleus/2.0a4/micronucleus: error while loading shared libraries: libusb-0.1.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus/wiki/Ubuntu-Linux helps.

Comment: Install `libusb-0.1-4` in whatever package manager KDE Neon uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem when using the snap package of the Arduino IDE. I solved the problem by installing the Arduino IDE from the official web page: https://www.arduino.cc/en/software

You might have to run the Arduino IDE with sudo or better add a custom udev rule in case you now get following assertion error:

> 'micronucleus_connect: Assertion `res >= 4' failed.'

Solving the assertion error is further described in following post: https://digistump.com/board/index.php?topic=106.0

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is working now.